# Failed to set property using reflection

Tags: c#, dynamic, reflection

I'm creating a dynamic class and using reflection to assign the property values, the class has two properties

```
public int Tipo_Pension {set;get;}
public bool Novedad_TDP {set;get;}
```

And I use the following code to set the values. VariableName is the name of the property and Value the real value of the property to set, and ruleMeta.Evaluator is the binder.

```
private void SetVariable(string VariableName, object Value, RuleMeta ruleMeta)
{
    o = ruleMeta.EvaluatorType.InvokeMember(
        VariableName,
        BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.SetProperty,
        Type.DefaultBinder,
        ruleMeta.Evaluator,
        new object[] { Value }
    );
}
```

The fist property, the Integer, works fine, but when its executed for the Boolean it fails and throws the next error

```
Method 'Cenet.RulesManager.Rule360788846.Novedad_TDP' not found
```

Any idea what could be happening?

Note: the object Value for the Boolean comes as a string: "false"

Comment: Try using `set_Novedad_TDP` as the method name.

Comment: You say you are creating a dynamic class, why not `((dynamic)ruleMeta).Novedad_TDP = Value` inside the method instead of using reflection? Assuming of course you parse `Value` into a `bool` first.

Comment: thats because you are passing string. you should pass bool value. use Convert.ToBoolean.

Comment: Yes  M.kazem Akhgary your are completely right, my bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As  M.kazem Akhgary  posted I was setting the bool with a string, simple as that.